# WebDav & IMAP In Alfresco

Tags: imap, alfresco, webdav, alfresco-share

Asking the following question in the context that any user could decide to upload a large volume of large files and affect availability of the system for all people using the system.

Is it advisable from a performance perspective to allow WebDav & IMAP traffic in Alfresco?

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a question about programming.  Server Administration questions should go to Serverfault.

Comment: I'd say you're probably even better off at a alfresco support forum.

Comment: As with anything performance-wise they are advisable within reason. You'll want to run performance tests if you're concerned.

Comment: Don't really understand the down votes as this is a perfectly legitimate question considering the other questions related to Alfresco asked on here.

Answer (score 2):

From a performance perspective WebDAV is not a very expensive protocol for Alfresco as long your users don't use sync tools. 
IMAP instead should be used only for very limited use cases or turned off because the implementation is traversing over the whole mount point again and again since Alfresco doesn't support idle mode. Traversing over the tree is like a stress test for your database.

Comment: could you enhance your answer by giving an example of the "sync tools" that you mentioned?

Comment: There are a lot. e.g. Windows offline folder, GoodSync, SyncToy
What they all have in common is that they traverse the whole tree (which is very expensive) and some of them store svn like artefacts in the share.
There are no good/robust working sync tools for Alfresco I know of. 
I would expect something like dropbox which support something like a event log which tracks changes on server and client